# How to get the field values of a content type in drupal

Tags: drupal, content-type, cck

How can I get the field value of a custom content type. I have created a custom content type using the CCK module. Is there any function to get the array of the fields of a particular content type.

For example: I can get the profile details using content_profile_load() function. Is there any function similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are viewing the node, the values are all stored in the `$node` variable.  Do a `print_r($node);`
to see all the available values in the node object.

Otherwise use node_load() to load a node object.  More on node_load(): http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7