# Trying to get the variables from fields in a node, getting error instead

Tags: php, drupal

Ok so I think maybe I'm not understanding how to do this.

I'm following the example here (or so I think):

[How to get the field values of a content type in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555883/how-to-get-the-field-values-of-a-content-type-in-drupal)

As far as I can tell, I should have a custom content type with at least one other field.

The content type should have a PHP-enabled field and I should enter the code `print_r($node);` inside `<?php ?>` and that should display all of the values of my fields.

That, however, is not what is occurring, instead I get this error when I create a node using the custom content type:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 1 of /hermes/waloraweb033/b418/moo.arao1989/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: node in eval() (line 1 of /hermes/waloraweb033/b418/moo.arao1989/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```

So why isn't my variable being defined? I am creating a custom node using the content type - shouldn't it be pulling the information for that particular node?

This is in Drupal 7

Comment: Why do you need `eval`? Everything can be done without eval in more efficient and secure way

Comment: Can you post some code? What are you executing?